# eclipse xpath element button location

Tags: selenium

I cannot locate this element by xpath or another option.

````
<button tabindex="0" class="jss65 jss59" type="button">
   <span class="jss64">
      <svg class="jss68" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true" role="presentation">
         <path d="M15.41 7.41L14 6l-6 6 6 6 1.41-1.41L10.83 12z"></path>
         <path fill="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z"></path>
      </svg>
   </span>
   <span class="jss77"></span>
</button>```
````

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Show what have you tried so far, problems you encountered, formulate your actual question. Help community to help you

Comment: Can you please post what you tried? Also, are you using Python, Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can locate this button using relative xPaths.  For example, the following relative xPath worked for me when locating this element:

```
//button[@class="jss65 jss59"]
```

For further information on how to customize your relative xPath, I would encourage reading up on this article: https://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html

Personally, however, if you have the option of changing this element, I would highly encourage the use of `id` within the `<button>` tag. This way, you have the option of locating the element by id, rather than by relying on xPath.  Since `id` is designed to always be unique per page, it can often be a much easier and reliable solution over xPath when locating an element.